# Inject Condition based Element in React

Tags: reactjs

I have build a small Component in react for Select Box:

```
const Select = (props) => (

    // var requireField;
    // if( props.requireField ) {
    //     requireField = (<span className="text-error">*</span>);
    // }

    // return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="form-label">{props.title}</label>
            <select
                name={props.name}
                value={props.selectedOption}
                onChange={props.controlFunc}
                className={["form-control", props.extraClass].join(' ')}>
                <option value="">{props.placeholder}</option>
            </select>
       </div>
    // );
);


Select.propTypes = {
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    extraClass: React.PropTypes.string,
    options: React.PropTypes.array,
    selectedOption: React.PropTypes.string,
    controlFunc: React.PropTypes.func,
    placeholder: React.PropTypes.string
};

export default Select;
```

And used it like this:

```
<div className="col-md-6">
    <Select
       title={'Building Name'}
       name={'building_name'}
       placeholder={'Choose building'} />
</div>
```

I was trying to add a new property `requireField` that will add a span with class based to `requireField == true`, As you can see i already tried in the above code, but this commented code generates the error that hard to detect in console as well. I am not even sure if its a right way to add the conditional properties in the given component. Please guide me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you define your component. After the arrow function you have used `(` which indicate that whatever is inside it is a part of the `return statement` and you cannot use `if statment` within a return statement, make use of `{}`. Do it like

```
const Select = (props) =>  {

     var requireField;
     if( props.requireField ) {
        requireField = (<span className="text-error">*</span>);
     }

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="form-label">{props.title}</label>
            <select
                name={props.name}
                value={props.selectedOption}
                onChange={props.controlFunc}
                className={["form-control", props.extraClass].join(' ')}>
                <option value="">{props.placeholder}</option>
            </select>
       </div>
    );
}
```